# problems usign paho.mqtt together with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

Im struggling on get python-telegram-bot working together with paho-mqqt.

something code in updater.start_polling() seems to influence the mqqt thread, that was started thru client.loop_start().

after a a few publishes the mqqt client stops receiving messages.

Does anybody have idea whats going on ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import telegram
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import logging
import time

#...


def start(bot, update):
    global client
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')
    client.publish("/doorR/test","test")


def on_connect(self,client, userdata, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    self.subscribe("/doorR/#")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Topic: ", msg.topic + "\nMessage: " + str(msg.payload))
    if msg.topic == "/doorR/status":
        bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=MYCHATID, text="Funkmodul status geändert: " + str(msg.payload))

def main():
    global client

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
    client.loop_start() 


    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    updater.start_polling()

    time.sleep(10)
    client.loop_stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Can you please share the output of your program or any other logs that can help?!

Comment: The script seems to be working perfectly for me. The only thing I changed was that I removed the last 2 lines from `main()`. As soon as you call the `loop_stop()`, mqtt stops processing.